# "Your connection is not secure" after using ng-attr-type angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a password input where I change its type with the ng-attr-type directive:

```
<input ng-attr-type="{{ showPassword ? 'text' : 'password' }}">
```

The problem is that now I get a warning message saying that my connection is not secure at the top of my browser. Do you know how to get rid of it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a password `<input>` and most likely your application is not running on HTTPS. Therefore your browser interprets a possible insecure connection since you'd be sending credentials over a non-encrypted protocol.

You'd have to enable HTTPS on your application in order to avoid seeing this error.

Comment: Ok so it has nothing to do with what I added. Thanks!

Comment: @Anna, well _technically_ it does since your `ng-attr-type` directive changes your `<input>` to a password input which is the reason you're seeing this.

Answer (score 1):

[As of Chrome 56](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn), web pages that contain a password or credit card input field that are not served over HTTPS will display security warnings. I believe that Firefox is planning on doing something similar (they may already have done so).

The only way to get rid of this warning is to configure your web server so it's using an SSL certificate. [Let's Encyrpt](https://letsencrypt.org/), which is a Linux Foundation project, will provide you with one for free.